# Functions implicitly taking in arguments

Tags: javascript

I am just curious as to why the function below works perfectly fine, although in its definition we can't see any arguments defined?

This does not seem to be intuitive to a starting JS developer.

```
const add = () => {
    return num => {
        const result = num + 10;
        return `Calculated! ${result}`;
    };
};

const addFn = add()
console.log(addFn(5)) // Calculated! 15
```

Comment: this is called `closure`, you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: @zb22: Note, though, that there are no values being closed over in this case.  There are no parameters to the `add` function and no local variables in scope that the returned function can access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're partially right. `add` takes no arguments.  If you supply any, they will be ignored.

But when you call `add`, you get back the function

```js
num => {
    const result = num + 10;
    return `Calculated! ${result}`;
}
```

which might be easier to recognize as a function if you wrapped its single argument in parentheses:

```js
(num) => {
    const result = num + 10;
    return `Calculated! ${result}`;
}
```

This new function takes (presumably) a number, adds 10 to it, and returns a formatted string including that result.

So this:

```js
const addFn = add()
```

simply assigns the value of `addFn` as this function returned by `add ()`, namely the function we describe above.

When we call it with `5`, it returns that formatted string involving  the result of `10 + 5`.

Does that make it any clearer?